# Dump SQLite table/DB without auto-generated columns (e.g id)

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite 3 database (`db`) like in this simplified example:

```
CREATE TABLE user(id integer primary key, name text);
INSERT INTO "user" VALUES(1,'user1');
INSERT INTO "user" VALUES(2,'user2');
```

If I enter `.dump`, sqlite will wrap these statements in a transaction and write them to the file `db.sql` previously defined with `.output`. This is fine if I need to import the data to an empty DB.

I want to be able to import the user data to a different DB with other users defined. If I try, I will most likely get something like this (as the ids may be used already in the target DB):

```
Error: near line 4: PRIMARY KEY must be unique
Error: near line 5: PRIMARY KEY must be unique
```

My approaches:

- I can tweak the dumped SQL manually to remove everything but the inserts and also remove the `id` column (mentioning only `name`) in the statement, but this approach does not scale as I want to automate the process.
- I can select from the db and write the SQL myself.

Is there any easy or more elegant approach that I am missing? `sqlite3` will be run from a Bash script in the real world problem.

Comment: Whicih OS? Can't you use `sed`?

Comment: @CL: It is Debian, so `sed` and typical Gnu tools will be available. Note that there may be other columns than `id` in my real-world example that need to be left out, and more such column names may be added after some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can automate the tweaking (but this still requires that you know the table structure):

```sh
$ (echo ".mode insert"; echo "SELECT name FROM user;") | \
  sqlite3 my.db | \
  sed -e 's/^INSERT INTO table /INSERT INTO user(name) /'
INSERT INTO user(name) VALUES('user1');
INSERT INTO user(name) VALUES('user2');
```

Comment: This method looks promising, unfortunatly I'm getting error `Error: unknown command or invalid arguments:  "mode". Enter ".help" for help`, looks like `sqlite3` doesn't like two lines separated by `\n`.

Comment: Okay, this one doesn't rely on quoting.

Comment: Awesome, worked like a charm, prefer this by far than creating a command text file :)